# Single-element parethesized expressions/tuples vs common use of parentheses

Tags: swift, tuples, parentheses

Sorry if this is trivial - I am so new to swift, actually I have only looked at the language guide+reference for a few minutes.

As far as I understand a parenthesized expression like `(2,3)` is used to construct a tuple, and `(2)` is a single-element tuple of type `(Int)`.

But then what happens with common use of parentheses like `(2+4)` in expression `(2+4)*5`? Is this still a tuple of type `(Int)` multiplied by an `Int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) in the Swift book:

> If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is
>   simply the type of that element. For example, the type of `(Int)` is
>   `Int`, not `(Int)`.

So the type of `(2)` or `(2+4)` is simply `Int`, and the `*` in `(2+4)*5` is
just integer multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. But even so, something appears to be wrong. E.g. would `(2)` match a tuple pattern? Would it be ok as an argument expecting a tuple?

Comment: @iavr: There seems to be no difference between `case let (x):` and `case let x:` in a switch statement, and both `2` and `(2)` match both patterns. As I understand it, `(foo)` is completely identical to `foo`.

Comment: I understand. I had in mind something more generic, e.g. a pattern like `(a...)` for any number of elements, like variadic functions in C++. I think this wouldn't work if single-element tuples are considered special.

Comment: @iavr: I don't think there is a pattern for tuples with variable length in Swift.

Comment: Yes, this was hypothetical. I like syntax `(2,3)` of course but I am concerned of what ambiguities it may bring, so it immediately caught my attention that swing has it, and was curious to see how it manages it.

Answer (score 0):

`+`, `*` etc are infix operators, and they have a semantic meaning that's different from the comma `,`, so the compiler treats it in a different way.