# Enclose right hand side of expression in Swift language

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, code-readability

Is there a way to enclose right hand side of an assignment expression in Swift using some brackets. I had the habit of using small brackets to enclose RHS of assignment expression in Objective C to make it more readable if the RHS is a big expression.

Adding a simple example
Example:

```
func function1() -> Bool {
    return // Returns a bool
}

func function2() -> Bool {
    return // Returns a bool
}

func findResult() {
    let result1 = function1() || function2()
    let result2 = (function1() || function2())
}
```

Now XCode shows inferred type of result1 as Bool and result2 as (Bool). Refer to attached images.
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to enclose complete RHS of the assignment expression inside brackets? It is not needed for above mentioned simple case but useful if RHS internally has many operators in it(Code readability).

Comment: Could you add some code as an example of what are you aiming to for the purpose of making it more clear?

Comment: As written the answer to your question is trivial: *Yes, exactly the same way you did it in Objective-C*. So guessing this is not what you are asking (as you surely would have tried that) you should edit your question to make it clear what you are asking, including code fragments to illustrate the question, and explain what errors you are getting. HTH

Comment: @crd have added example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ahmad-f have added example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kishoretheju: What is the problem with your code? Both lines in `func findResult()` are correct. What would you like to do differently, and why? How would you do it in Objective-C?

Comment: @MartinR, is Bool same as (Bool). In objective C for both cases it was Bool.

Comment: My Xcode 9.1 displays is as "Bool" but anyway, there is no difference at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767902/1187415

Comment: Thanks @MartinR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MartinR mentioned has mentioned link to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767681/single-element-parethesized-expressions-tuples-vs-common-use-of-parentheses/24767902#24767902) where it is confirmed Bool and (Bool) are same. Thanks martin for help.