# Single element tuple in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

How can I create a single element tuple in Swift?

```
var a = 10
var tup = (a,)
print(tup)
```

But this code gives me a build-time error.

also,

I cannot write `var tup = (a)`, as this just creates an integer variable.

Comment: A single element tuple is the normal variable. The same way in mathematics a 1-tuple is a scalar value.

Comment: There is no real “single-element tuple” in Swift, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/24767681/1187415.

Comment: What is advantage of single tuple! if you want to use single tuple just use a variable.

Comment: Do you want to store anything else in the tuple later for which you want to keep space in it?

Comment: In other programming languages like python, there is a concept of single-element tuple. So, I thought swift might also have it.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need it or in what context you are going to use it. Why must it be a tuple rather than the type of the first element?

Comment: Having 1-tuple being reduced to just an element was design decision and was there since first release language version.

Comment: Does `var tup = (a, _)` work ?

Comment: What about `var tuple: (hello: String, String?) = (hello: "world", nil)` ?

Comment: @Koen, `'_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

What about this solution?

```
 typealias SingleTuple = (Int, Void)

 var a = 10
 var tup: SingleTuple = (a, ())
 print(tup)
```

Comment: You could store `nil` instead. But I don't think OP asked that.

Comment: No this was not what I was looking for.

Comment: We can directly store var tup = (a, nil).