# Why does Swift accept code that should return a tuple, but instead returns a string?

Tags: swift, string, function, return, tuples

In the following code, I would expect Xcode not to accept because I'm using a string as the return value in the body of the code instead of a tuple. But for some reason, Xcode doesn't return an error. Why is that?

```
func test(name: String) -> (String) {
    return name
}
```

Comment: `T` and `(T)` are the same types, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767681/single-element-parethesized-expressions-tuples-vs-common-use-of-parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's special treatment for tuples of 0 or 1 element. As far as the type system is concerned:

- `()` is equivalent to `Void()`
- `(T)` is equivalent to `T`

Comment: Ah, and there's no way this code would break because it's written to never accept more than one element in the "name" parameter? I wonder if I should avoid using this syntax since it looks sloppy, or if it's actually valuable at some point.

Comment: What is `Void()`? Did you mean `Void`?

Comment: @John I didn't understand the first half of your question at all, but as for the second part, just write `func test(name: String) -> String`.

Comment: @MartinR Try it. `func f(_ void: Void) {}; f(Void())` Void is a type, and can't be used directly. You can either instantiate it using `Void()` (but not `Void.init()`, interestingly), or use it as a metatype with `Void.sef`, but you can't use it directly.

Comment: Actually, have a look at the documentation of `Void`, it's just a typealias for the empty tuple: `typealias Void = ()`. The fact that `Void()` is valid is quite weird though, I had no idea that works, but the type system doesn't always treat `Void` and `()` the same way (for instance when returning `Void` in a `Result`, you cannot use `Void`, even though that should be replaced with `()`, since its just a typealias.

Comment: @Alexander: You are right. `()` can be both  a type (`Void`) and  a value of that type. The latter is a  `Void()`, I had never used that before.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Some of the confusion stems from `()` being both a type (the empty tuple) and a value (the only possible instance of an empty tuple). `return ()` makes sense, because it's returning a value. It makes sense that `return Void` doesn't work, because it's referring to `()` the type, not `()` the value, akin to `return type(of: ())`. The other behaviour is still perplexing. I asked about it on the forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-illegal/30795?u=alexanderm

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, it's little-known, and behaves oddly: https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-illegal/30795?u=alexanderm

Comment: @Alexander for some reason I never actually realised that `()` is the actual type itself as well, but now it does make more sense, thanks!